# thymeleaf inline text is not working when dynamically generating an expression using concatenation

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf in my Spring MVC project. I need to dynamically build the data-url using the id supplied as part of the query string. I am using JQuery upload plug-in to upload the documents attached.

This is required output (for a given query string of serverId=10)

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="/upload?myId=10"/>
```

Here is the Thymeleaf code

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" th:inline="text" data-url="/upload?myId=[[${serverId}]]"/>
```

I also tried variations, but moving th:inline to parent tags, and tried none and javascript values for th:inline. Other variations that I tried are

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" th:inline="text" data-url="[[@{/upload/${serverId}}]]">

<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" th:inline="text" data-url="[[/upload/${serverId}]]">
```

None of these work. `${serverId}` is resolved only if its a plain text, but if try to use it any other way, it does not work. Tried different combinations of th:with and th:attr but no success yet.

Anyone have had similar issues? Please suggest.

Comment: or alternatively, if I can pass the parameter to jquery file upload plugin, by passing the same serverId, that would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get this one solved myself. I had to use `th:attr`

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" th:inline="text" data-url="" th:attr="data-url=@{'/upload?myId='+${serverId}}"/>
```